# Change Google Fusion URL via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want to change query of google fusion with jquery, here's my map:

```
var fusionid= "";
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {lat: 28.3268, lng: 84.1855},
    zoom: 7
});

  var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    heatmap: { enabled: false },
    query: {
      select: fusionid,
      from: "1vgijexVJcXVdOP5b80dwzlLOUVv_fI8gr7fZyU-e",
      where: ""
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    }
  });
}
```

I'm trying to change the fusion id with jquery, but nothing happened:

```
$('#tm-male-2013').click(function(){
   fusionid = "1vgijexVJcXVdOP5b80dwzlLOUVv_fI8gr7fZyU-e";
   initMap();
});
$('#tm-male-2014').click(function(){
    fusionid = "some other id";
    initMap();
});
```

Why it didn't work??

Answer (score 0):

Finally,
I found great solution to switching fusion table style, we don't need to create many fusion table like I did, only use one fusion table than create some map style by duplicating the maps. Then it will generate `styleId` and `templateId`. Here's the example:

```
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {lat: 28.3268, lng: 84.1855},
    zoom: 7
  });

  var fussion = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
      query: { select: "col0", from: '1XjEJd8JR-c3yHaSyrKC_mN8LCY1YG1Kiazn5TXlG'},
      options: { styleId: 2, templateId: 2}
    });

fussion.setMap(map);

$('#tm-male-2013').click(function(){
    fussion.setMap(null);
    fussion = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        map: map,
        heatmap: { enabled: false },
        query: { select: "col0", from: '1XjEJd8JR-c3yHaSyrKC_mN8LCY1YG1Kiazn5TXlG'},
        options: { styleId: 2, templateId: 2}
      });
    fussion.setMap(map);
  });
  $('#tm-male-2014').click(function(){
    fussion.setMap(null);
    fussion = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        map: map,
        heatmap: { enabled: false },
        query: { select: "col0", from: '1XjEJd8JR-c3yHaSyrKC_mN8LCY1YG1Kiazn5TXlG'},
        options: { styleId: 6, templateId: 7}
      });
    fussion.setMap(map);
  });
```

Please vote if this answer help you out.

Thank you,